# Fastest architecture for multithreaded web crawler

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

There should be a frontier object  - Holding a set of visited and waiting to crawl URL's.
There should be some thread responsible for crawling web pages.
There would be also some kind of controller object to create crawling threads.

I don't know what architecture would be faster, easier to extend. How to divide responsibilities to make as as few synchronization as possible and also minimize number of checking if current URL has been already visited.

Should controller object be responsible of providing new URL's to working threads - this mean working threads will need to crawl all given URL's and then sleep for undefined time. Controller will be interpreting this threads so crawling thread should handle `InterruptedException` (How expensive it is in Java - it seems that exception handling is not very fast ). 
Or maybe controller should only starts the threads and let crawling threads to fetch frontier themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a shared, thread-safe list with the URL's to be crawled.  create an Executor with the number of threads corresponding to the number of crawlers you desire to run concurrently.  start your crawlers as Runnables with a reference to the shared list and submit each of them to the Executor.  each crawler removes the next URL from the list and does whatever you need it to do, looping until the list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a few years since this question was asked, but in Nov 2015 we are currently using [frontera](https://github.com/scrapinghub/distributed-frontera) and [scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd)

Scrapy uses twisted which makes it a good multithreaded crawler, and on multi-core machines that means we are only limited by the inbound bandwidth. Frontera-distributed uses hbase and kafka to score links and keep all the data accessible to clients.

Answer (score 1):

Create a central resource with a hash map that can store URL as key with last time scanned. Make this thread safe. Then just spawn threads with links in a queue which can be picked up by the crawlers as starting point. Each thread would then carry on crawling and updating the resource. A thread in the resource clears up outdated crawls. The in memory resource can be serialised at start or it could be in a db depending on your app needs.

You could make this resource accessible via remote services to allow multiple machines. You could make the resource itself spread over several machines by segregating urls. Etc...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a blocking queue, that contains urls that need to be fetched. In this case you could create multiple consumers that will fetch urls in multiple threads. If queue is empty, than all fetchers will be locked. In this case you should run all threads at the beginning and should not controll them later.
Also you need to maintain a list of already downloaded pages in some persistent storage and check before adding to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, why not look at [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org).